# Не работает предпросмотр видео в Tik Tok Live Studio(на базе OBS)

Tags: obs

Я один из немногих кому ТикТок дал возможность вести эфиры с компьютера через свою программу Live Studio(насколько знаю это урезанная OBS). Все попытки выйти в эфир не увенчались успехом, проблема в том, что какие я источники не добавляю - в предпросмотре всё равно чёрный экран. Кстати OBS работает нормально. Менял дравера видеокарты - не помогло. Год назад всё работало на этом ноубуке, сегодня - нет. Что может давать такую проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там вроде какая-то суета вокруг TikTok Live Studio... их обвинили в нарушении лицензионного соглашения OBS Studio. И насколько я понимаю сейчас никто через него уже не стримит, т.к. лавочку прикрыли (на время или навсегда)...во всяком случае в текузем виде

Comment: они мне просто неделю назад прислали уведомление, что я могу стримить через приложение, значит должно работать? )))

Comment: вы нашли решение этой проблемы с чёрным экраном?